# Applying Ito's formula and characteristic pair

Tags: functions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Consider the following process:

$$X_t=\sin^2(W_t) + t,$$ where $W$ is Brownian Motion.

First define $f(t, x):= \sin^2(x) +t$.

This yields $$ dX_t=df(t, W_t)= f_t(t, W_t) dt + f_x(t, W_t)dW_t + \frac{1}{2}f_{xx} (t, W_t) dW_td W_t 
$$

$$= 1 dt + 2 \sin W_t \cos W_t dW_t + (\cos^2 W_t -\sin^2 W_t) dt$$ $$ = (1+ \cos^2 W_t -\sin^2 W_t ) dt  + 2 \sin W_t \cos W_t d W_t$$

Is it formally ok? The characteristic pair would be $(1+ \cos^2 W_t -\sin^2 W_t,  2 \sin W_t \cos W_t  )$

Is this the right interpretation?

Comment: What is $Y_{t}$? What is a characteristic pair?

Comment: It was meant as an arbitrary variable. I replaced it with x. I only wanted to apply Ito's formula to this function. Is it right in that way?

Comment: Consider an Ito process: $dX_t= \mu(t) dt + \sigma(t) d W_t$. Then $(\mu, \sigma)$ is reffered to as  the characteristic pair.

Comment: looks reasonable then to me